# Writing a method to return the string inside an object in Java

Tags: java, object

I'm really new to Java and programming in general (~3 weeks of experience) so sorry if this question is obvious for you guys. I tried searching for answers here but couldn't find any that fit my specific problem. And yeah it's for school, I'm not trying to hide it.

Here I'm supposed to write an object method that returns the string contained in the object oj, in reverse. I do know how to print a string in reverse, but I don't know how I should call the object since the method isn't supposed to have any parameters.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Oma{
public static void main(String[] args){
    final Random r = new Random();


    final String[] v = "sininen punainen keltainen musta harmaa valkoinen purppura oranssi ruskea".split(" ");
    final String[] e = "etana koira kissa possu sika marsu mursu hamsteri koala kenguru papukaija".split(" ");


    OmaMerkkijono oj = new OmaMerkkijono(v[r.nextInt(v.length)] + " " + e[r.nextInt(e.length)]);

    String reve = oj.printreverse();
    System.out.println(reve);
    }
}
 class OmaMerkkijono{
     private String jono;

     public OmaMerkkijono(String jono){
        this.jono=jono;
     }


     public String printreverse(){
     //so here is my problem, i tried calling the object in different ways 
     //but none of them worked

         return reversedstringthatdoesnotexist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate by adding code where you are getting the error while making the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this to your "printreverse" method :

```
 new StringBuilder(this.jono).reverse().toString()
```

With this, when you call the method with the object "oj":

```
String reve = oj.printreverse();
```

After the previous line, "reve" must contain the value of the String reversed.

Olet hyvä, moi moi!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that I should've just used the string variable inside the class instead of trying to call the object outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

To revers a String use `StringBuilder` and `reverse()`

```
public String printreverse(){
    return new StringBuilder(jono).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access private attributes from outside the class you use what are called accessors and mutators, aka getters and setters.

Comment: I did have them them, including a lot of other stuff, but deleted them for this to get rid of the unnecessary stuff since I only needed help with this one method. So sorry about that, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a basic getter that also reverses the string.

```
public class MyObject {

    private String objectName;

    MyObject(String objectName) {
        this.objectName = objectName;
    }

    public String getObjectName() {
        return objectName; // returns objectName in order
    }

    public String getReversedObjectName() {
        return new StringBuilder(objectName).reverse().toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject teslaRoadster = new MyObject("Telsa Roadster");
        System.out.println(teslaRoadster.getObjectName());
        System.out.println(teslaRoadster.getReversedObjectName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Telsa Roadster
retsdaoR asleT
```